# How to test the response content-type using SOAP UI

Tags: java, rest, soap, soapui, resteasy

I am new to this SOAP UI .
I got a requirement to test if the response body is not empty .

Can you please tell me how to solve.

My idea was to check the `content-length` of the response using assertion script but it is not working for `equals()`.

`contains()` is working but **not `equals`**:

```
// works:
assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]).contains("0")
// not working:
assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["C‌​ontent-Length"]).equals("0") 
// not working:
assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["C‌​ontent-Length"]) == 0
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Where's the `equals` you mention?

Comment: assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]).equals("0") (or) assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]) == 0  None of them are working.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
// works:
assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]).contains("0")
// not working:
assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["C‌​ontent-Length"]).equals("0") 
// not working:
assert ((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringList)messageExchange.responseHeaders["C‌​ontent-Length"]) == 0
```

The expression `messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]` returns a `StringList`<sup>[[see doc here]](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/types/StringList.html)</sup>, which is a `ArrayList<String>`.

It's content would be something like several `Strings`, like (`"abc"`, `"def"`, `"ghi"`).

#### `contains("0")`:

This way, when you call `list.contains("abc")`, you are asking if the `"abc"` is one of the elements of the list. Your `Content-Length` header is probably a list with one element, like (`"0"`). That's why `list.contains("0")` returns `true`, because the `String` `"0"` is one of the elements on the list.

#### `equals("0")`:

So, when you call: `list.equals(something)`, it will only return `true` if the `something` passed as parameter is a list of `String`s as well. `"0"` is not a list of `String`s, it is just one.

#### `== 0`:

Same way, when you call `list == 0` you are testing if `list` is the integer `0`, which is not.

`messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"] == 0` should not work because. `messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]` returns a **`List` of `String`s**, that is **different** than the integer number `0`.

`messageExchange.getResponse().getContentLength() == 0` works because `messageExchange.getResponse().getContentLength()` returns the `Content-Length` header as a `long` integer value.

`messageExchange.getResponse().getContentLength()` is the same as getting the first value of the list and converting to `long`. Look how this will work: `Long.valueOf(messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"].get(0)) == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . If it is like that then assert messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"] == 0 should work ? which is not.

Comment: The below script works assert  messageExchange.getResponse().getContentLength() == 0;

Comment: `messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"] == 0` should not work. `messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"]` returns a **List of Strings**, that is **different** than the integer number `0`.

Comment: `messageExchange.getResponse().getContentLength() == 0` works because `messageExchange.getResponse().getContentLength()` returns a `long` integer value. `messageExchange.getResponse().getContentLength()` is the same as getting the first value of the list and converting to `long`. Look how this will work: `Long.valueOf(messageExchange.responseHeaders["Content-Length"].get(0)) == 0`.

Comment: @acdcjunior +1 for patience and trying to teach a real newbie